# I need help to make data coherent in excel

Tags: excel, database

I have database where a some data is inconsistent. This database summarize different variables among 10.000 industrial firms (e.g. number of employees, energy consumption, value of assets, among another 83 variables) over 10 years. My issue is that the firms change over time the International Standard Industrial Classification (ISIC) code and I need to put the same code to the firm in order to make a coherent analysis.

[image]

In the image you can see how the firm 987653 has two different ISIC code (textiles and Food manufacturing)

It is possible to have some help to create a formula to put a new ISIC code based on the most repeated value (in the example of the firm 987653 will be food manufacturing).

Comment: How is the data entered into the worksheet?  Have you done anything to try to solve this problem on your own?:

Comment: If you wanted to use the first ISIC entered, you could use a helper column with a simple `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Hi Ron! thanks a lot for your answer. I'm not sure if I follow your question in how the data is entered - is a database compiled from the national statistics agency. Initially I tried to do it manually but I have almost 90.000 entries. Then I tried with the index formula but I have not been successful so far.

Comment: How does the data get from the national database to your desktop?  Is it an Excel file? Is it some other kind of file?  And see also my second comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ron. It's a excel file, I tried VLOOKUP but the value that I got it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following array formula to find most used code:

```
{=INDEX($D$2:$D$23,MODE(IF($A$2:$A$23=A2,MATCH($D$2:$D$23,$D$2:$D$23,0))))}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help basic! For some reason I cannot enter the array formula Im pressing ctrl+shift+enter. Is there any option that I have to turn on?

Comment: @LuisCRestrepo Strange. Which excel version you are using?

Comment: Microsoft Excel for Office 365 32 bit

Comment: There you need to be able to enter an array formula without restrictions.  You may not even need to press ctrl + shift + enter - it will work with simple enter. What happens when you press ctr + shift + enter? What result do you see?

Comment: I does not work, the formula is pasted as text in the cell. Pressing either, enter or ctrl + shift + enter, remains as text

Comment: It worked! I just erased the { } in the formula and with ctr + shift + enter is working perfectly!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A simple `VLOOKUP` should do what you want, if you can live with using the first ISIC for the company.  eg:

```
F2: =VLOOKUP(B2,$B$1:$E$10,4,FALSE)
```

[image]